# Proper usage of 'form_for', using the :url parameter or can I put the :action directly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference the two lines bellow. The only difference is the usage of ***:url =>***

1- The following line in my view is generating an error (removing form_for removes the error and rendering is done with no error):

```
<%= form_for( [@company, @appointment], :action => 'company_edit', :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

I spent a lot of time trying to make sense of the error, but I do not know where 'company_edit'is coming from.

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `company_appointment_path' for #<#<Class:0x5047cc8>:0x5045070>):
9:       </div>
10:       <div class="widget-content nopadding">
11:         <!--form action="#" method="get" class="form-horizontal"-->
12:         <%= form_for([@company, @appointment], :action => 'company_edit', :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
13:           <% if @appointment.errors.any? %>
14:             <div class="control-group">
15:                 <div id="error_explanation">
app/views/appointments/company_edit.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_appointments_company_edit_html_erb___287242072_42128364'
```

Here is a ***snippet*** of my route file:

```
resources :companies do

  resources :appointments, only: [:company_edit] do
    member do
      get 'company_edit', :as => :company_edit
    end
  end
end
```

2- I found that using :url, made all work again, but why?

```
<%= form_for([@company, @appointment], :url => {:action => 'company_edit'}, :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}) do |f| %>
```

I'm trying to understand this since I use 'form_for' in many places and I have never used ':url =>' before and I want to know if I was not using 'form_for' correctly and that I now need to update my code to properly use the helper.

---

### EDIT

This is my controller:

```
def company_edit
    @appointment = Appointment.find(params[:id])
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])

end
```

Comment: show your controller code

Comment: I think only: can hold things like :create, :edit, :new, :delete, :show, :index, :update.  I don't think you can put :next_state in there (for example).  Try typing 'rake routes' to see what routes were generated.

Comment: It's only a snippet of my routes, don't want to put all of it, it's pointless. I edited it to show only my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the answer to your question is no.

`:action` is not an options parameter recognized by `form_for`.

Here's the API:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

`:url` is an option it recognizes and itself includes an options hash which includes `:action`.

I hope that helps.